# how to run executable via processBuilder?

Tags: java

I'm trying to run mencoder with options in linux via processBuilder, but I can only run it from xterm. When I'm trying to run it directly I get error in mencoder.
To explain better, I have a jtexfield which displays all parameters for mencoder, and the input and output paths. This is editable and I can change some parameters there. Then by press the "start" button mencoder runs with all those parameters to convert the file. This works fine, using xterm:

```
 String[] command= {"/usr/bin/xterm","-e",
 lblCommand.getText().toString()}; 
                try {
                    proc = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

but I don't want to have an external terminal running. So I'm trying to run mencoder directly and display the output on the jtextfield. This works also, but mencoder doesn't work as before.
If I use code this instead:

```
String command= {"/usr/bin/mencoder",lblCommand.getText().toString()}; 
                try {
                    proc = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

then I get no such file of directory error:

> > java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/mencoder -sub "/media/Data/input.srt" -subcp iso-8859-7 -spualign 2 -subpos 96
> >     -subfont-text-scale 3.3 -vf pp=lb -ovc lavc -lavcopts vbitrate=1200 -oac copy "/media/Data/input.avi" -o "/media/Data/dvd/test.avi"": error=2, No such file or directory  at
> >     java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)  at
> >     burnsub.MainWindow$3.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:190)     at
> >     javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
> >       at
> >     javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
> >       at
> >     javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
> >       at
> >     javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
> >       at
> >     javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
> >       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)    at
> >     javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
> >     java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
> >     java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
> >     java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
> >     java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
> >     java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
> >     java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
> >       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
> >       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
> >     java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
> >     java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
> >     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> >     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
> >       at
> >     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
> >       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
> >     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> >     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
> >       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
> >       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> >     Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory    at
> >     java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)  at
> >     java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:247)    at
> >     java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)     at
> >     java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)  ... 37 more
> >     Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
> >       at burnsub.MainWindow$3.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:195)    at
> >     javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
> >       at
> >     javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
> >       at
> >     javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
> >       at
> >     javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
> >       at
> >     javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
> >       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)    at
> >     javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
> >     java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
> >     java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
> >     java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
> >     java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
> >     java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
> >     java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
> >       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
> >       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
> >     java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
> >     java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
> >     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> >     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
> >       at
> >     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
> >       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
> >     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> >     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
> >       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
> >       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Is there any other way to achive this?

Comment: What happens when you open a new xterm and lauch the generated command there? You have to get rid of all the 
superfluous quotes. 
"/usr/bin/mencoder -sub "/media/Data/input.srt" -subcp iso-8859-7 -spualign 2 -subpos 96 -subfont-text-scale 3.3 -vf pp=lb -ovc lavc -lavcopts vbitrate=1200 -oac copy "/media/Data/input.avi" -o "/media/Data/dvd/test.avi""

Comment: The command works fine on native terminal

Comment: The extra quotes at start and end, displayed only on the error message. The command is this exactly:/usr/bin/mencoder -sub "/media/Data/input.srt" -subcp iso-8859-7 -spualign 2 -subpos 96 -subfont-text-scale 3.3 -vf pp=lb -ovc lavc -lavcopts vbitrate=1200 -oac copy "/media/Data/input.avi" -o "/media/Data/dvd/test.avi"